# How to configure aws lambda to send api requests with ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

Recently I am trying to use api for trading without much knowing about the theories. And successfully create a working function and deployed it in aws lambda . Now I am trying some another exchanges and their api creation forms have place for ip address .

I tried searching on internet about this, but did not find anything.
I think the request need to send from the ip address.

Can someone tell me how to tackle this problem. Can I simply change something in lambda and do the thing??

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Comment: @Marcin I setup everything from this [article](https://medium.com/financial-engines-techblog/aws-lambdas-with-a-static-outgoing-ip-5174a1e70245). Now I have some questions. 1. How to check if my function always send via exact ip?? 2. My lambda already have a api gateway trigger, can I add another events trigger?? 3. To create another lambda do I need to create another vpc or can I use this vpc and eip???

Comment: I would suggest making new question for your new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I simply change something in lambda and do the thing??

You have to setup a [VPC with private subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html) and a [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) in a public subnet if you don't have such VPC already. Then you [associate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) your lambda function with the private subnet.

This way your lambda function will access the external api using the NAT. The good thing about NAT is that it has **static public IP** which you can whitelist at your API provider.